# Django: Where does "DoesNotExist" come from?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

All the time in Django I see `DoesNotExist` being raised like in `db.models.fields.related.py`. Not `ObjectDoesNotExist` which is defined in `django.core.exceptions`, but just `DoesNotExist`. Where is this exception class defined, or am I not fully understanding exceptions? I've checked that it's not in exceptions (at least not that I know of). I'm confused obviously.

Note: It also comes free, as an attribute of a model sub-class instance, like `self.someforeignkey.DoesNotExist. How is this possible?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`DoesNotExist` is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-do-not-return-querysets):

> The DoesNotExist exception inherits
>   from
>   django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist,
>   so you can target multiple
>   DoesNotExist exceptions.

so you can perfectly well use `except ObjectDoesNotExist:` and catch all the model-specific `DoesNotExist` exceptions that might be raised in the `try` clause, or use `except SomeSpecificModel.DoesNotExist:` when you want to be more specific.

If you're looking for the specific spot in Django's source code where this attribute is added to model classes, see [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#zR2MFhsc1E4/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/base.py?format=txt&format=txt&q=%22DoesNotExist%20=%22%20lang:python&d=2), lines 34-37:

```
# Create the class.
new_class = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, {'__module__': attrs.pop('__module__')})
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(attrs.pop('Meta', None)))
new_class.add_to_class('DoesNotExist', types.ClassType('DoesNotExist', (ObjectDoesNotExist,), {}))
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I didn't know Django had that add_to_class() method. I did a document search in Komodo for 'class DoesNotExist' and was beating my head on the wall.

Comment: Unless there is a need to disambiguate which class is the source of the `DoesNotExist` (very rare in my experience), it is safer to user `ObjectDoesNotExist`.

Comment: I think that in almost every situation it's 100% better to know which exception was raised. A blanket `except ObjectDoesNotExist:` is no better than `except:`. Since you don't know what caused the exception, you're program will potentially be acting on bad information.

Answer (score 7):

`DoesNotExist`, just like `MultipleObjectsReturned`, is an attribute on a model class. It is added to the model when the model is generated.

EDIT: The metaclass responsible for this process is `ModelBase` (`django.db.models.base`) and you may look at it to see what is going on.