# Django DoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am having issues on trying to figure "DoesNotExist Errors", I have tried to find the right way for manage the no answer results, however I continue having issues on "DoesNotExist" or "Object hast not Attribute DoestNotExists"

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.utils import simplejson

from vehicles.models import *
from gpstracking.models import *


def request_statuses(request):

    data = []
    vehicles = Vehicle.objects.filter()
    Vehicle.vehicledevice_
    for vehicle in vehicles:
        try:
            vehicledevice = vehicle.vehicledevice_set.get(is_joined__exact = True)
            imei = vehicledevice.device.imei
            try:
                lastposition = vehicledevice.device.devicetrack_set.latest('date_time_process')
                altitude = lastposition.altitude
                latitude = lastposition.latitude
                longitude =  lastposition.longitude
                date_time_process = lastposition.date_time_process.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                date_time_created = lastposition.created.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            except Vehicle.vehicledevice.device.DoesNotExist:
                lastposition = None
                altitude = None
                latitude = None
                longitude = None
                date_time_process = None
                date_time_created = None
        except Vehicle.DoesNotExist:
            vehicledevice = None
            imei = ''

        item = [
                vehicle.vehicle_type.name,
                imei,
                altitude,
                "Lat %s Lng %s" % (latitude, longitude),
                date_time_process,
                date_time_created,
                '', 
                ''
                ]
        data.append(item)
    statuses = {
                "sEcho": 1,
                "iTotalRecords": vehicles.count(),
                "iTotalDisplayRecords": vehicles.count(),
                "aaData": data
                } 
    json = simplejson.dumps(statuses)
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2143599/3015186

Answer (score 199, accepted):

I have found the solution to this issue using ObjectDoesNotExist on this way

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
......

try:
  # try something
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
  # do something
```

After this, my code works as I need

Thanks any way, your post help me to solve my issue

Comment: That'll work, but it's not really the best way. You should figure what class of object is represented by `vehicledevice.device.devicetrack_set`, and then catch `<That class>.DoesNotExist`.

Comment: I was trying to find that, also I was trying to guess, cause I couldn't find the solution, after reading some doc I found this way
Could you try to edit the code please

Comment: Look in the class that represents `vehicledevice.device`, and find out what the related model for the `devicetrack` attribute is.

Comment: (It's not possible for me to determine that without your model definitions.)

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually included the exact output of the exception that is occurring

Comment: @mipadi would be nice to know WHY it is so important to use the `ActualClass.DoesNotExist` exception?

Comment: I'm assuming it's important so that you're not inadvertently catching a `DoesNotExist` for something else...the whole "explicit is better than implicit" zen stuff

Answer (score 176):

This line

```
 except Vehicle.vehicledevice.device.DoesNotExist
```

means look for device *instance* for DoesNotExist exception, but there's none, because it's on class level, you want something like

```
 except Device.DoesNotExist
```

Comment: I have tried to do that but the debug on firefox gives me:

DoesNotExist at /tracking/request/statuses
VehicleDevice matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'is_joined__exact': True}

Comment: This is expected and only means that you request an object that does not indeed exist. You should look at your data, or the logic behind it

Comment: Thanks for you help I have found my answer on a exception management using ObjectDoesNotExist

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: I meant to upvote this answer, but by accident downvoted. As I discovered too late I am unable to change my vote from down to up, sorry...

Answer (score 26):

The solution that i believe is best and optimized is:

```
try:
   #your code
except "ModelName".DoesNotExist:
   #your code
```

Answer (score 9):

First way:

```
try:
   # Your code goes here
except Model.DoesNotExist:
   # Handle error here
```

Another way to handle not found in Django. It raises Http404 instead of the model’s DoesNotExist exception.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def get_data(request):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Model, pk=1)
```

Comment: Model.DoesNotExist doesn't works for me. Next answer is fine.