# DoesNotExist at /folder/ Userdata matching query does not exist. DJango Problem

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

When i use my super acc, this error does not shows up, but when I tried to use other acc. this error shows up. where did I do wrong?
The error : DoesNotExist at /voting/
Userdata matching query does not exist.

My Model :

```
class Userdata(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Fakultas, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    is_voted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self): return self.user.username
```

My views :

```
@login_required
def voted(response):
    user = Userdata.objects.get(id=response.user.id)  # get the username
    if user.is_voted:
        return render(response, 'Main/voting.html', {'calon': Voting.objects.order_by('id'), 'hasil': 'You Have Voted'})
    if response.method == 'POST':
        id = response.POST['idcalon']
        calon2 = Voting.objects.get(id=id)  # get user selection in html
        user.is_voted = True
        calon2.voters += 1
        user.save()
        calon2.save()
    return render(response, 'Main/voting.html', {'calon': Voting.objects.order_by('id')})  # balik ke sendiri
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django DoesNotExist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181188/django-doesnotexist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User` and `UserData` don't have the same primary key. So  `Userdata.objects.get(id=response.user.id)` will not work because there is no such `Userdata` with the given user's id. But you do not need that, because `User` and `Userdata` have [OneToOne relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField). So simply use this:

```
user = response.user.userdata
```