# clients.models.Clients.DoesNotExist: Clients matching query does not exist. - django python

Tags: python, django

this is how I solve the problem `clients.models.Clients.DoesNotExist: Clients matching query does not exist`

```
for r in orders_page:
   try:
      cls2 = cls.objects.get(related_uuid=r.related_uuid)
      related_list.append(cls2)
   except clients.models.Clients.DoesNotExist:
      pass
```

is there any better solution for `get` empty?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181188/django-doesnotexist this would help I hope

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'built in' way to do this. Django will raise the DoesNotExist exception every time if the object does not exist .